# WebToCase RetURL Not Working

Tags: apex, html, web-to-case

I think I'm doing something wrong... I'm posting a web-to-case form and giving a retURL, but when I submit the form it just hangs on the Salesforce page.

note: i'm using nextjs/react and iterating through an array of objects.

```
    type: "hidden",
    name: "retURL",
    value: "http://localhost:3000",
  },
```

Here's what the payload looks like when I inspect the network request for webtocase

```
retURL: http://localhost:3000
email: tester@email.com
xx: 55555555555
xx: 1234567
xx: Electrical
xx: Emergency
xx: help
```

Is there some kind of configuration I'm missing? Could it be a bunch of apex classes running on a trigger when the form is submitted? Unlikely but spitballing

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can't redirect to localhost... set the retURL to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and it worked.